# Hotel man, what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this [article](https://www.wired.com/story/a-math-genius-blooms-late-and-conquers-his-field/), there is a phrase: hotel man.

> “I asked him if he wanted a hotel and he said he’s not a hotel man. That’s what he said. So he stayed in one corner of my apartment,” Hironaka said.

I don't understand what does it mean by a hotel man.

Could you please explain it to me?

Thanks.

Comment: '*I asked him if he wanted a hotel and he said he’s not a hotel man*' - he doesn't like hotels.

Comment: I think it means that he is not the person who usally stays in   hotels , but he'd rather  have other, probably less expensive, accomodation.

Comment: Yea, just means he doesn't prefer hotels and so he is not the person to ask.

Comment: Thanks. I also understand like you said but the next sentence That's what he said makes me a little bit confused. Is it a way to emphasize that the man doesn't like hotel?

Comment: It's simply using a noun (hotel) as an adjective (well, a descriptor at any rate; from trying to find a duplicate question it appears it may not really be an "adjective" as such). A "hotel man" is a man who likes hotels, much as a "people person" is somebody who gets on well with other people, or the "computer guy" is someone who is good with computers.

Answer (score 5):

As the comments suggest, colloquial English ( or USA-ian English) allows you to use pretty much any noun or gerund in an adjectivial form to modify "man," indicating you do or don't like/partake of/fit in with  the named object or concept.

"I'm your back door man."   "I'm a dark beer man."  "He's a meat-and-potatoes guy," although that one is a bit of an idiom.
"I'm not an opera guy."